# how to make bottomNav appears on screens that are not defined in it? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-bottomnavigation

I've created a BottomNav that has 4 buttons and it navigates fine between them.
But i want this BottomNav to be visible in all screens of the app (those screens that are not directly attached to the BottomNav).

for example: my bottomNav has 4 screens **(home, profile, notices, and more)**, the bottomNav appears perfectly in them, but i want it to appear also in another 2 screens **(permissions, vacations)** which are accessed from button in **Home** screen

How can I approach such a thing?

here's my BottomNav code to be clear:

```
int _selectedIndex = 0; 
//list of widgets that already exist on the bottomNav
  static List<Widget> _screens = <Widget>[
    PermissionsRequestScreen(),
    HomeScreen(title: 'Home'),
    NoticesScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
    MoreScreen(),
  ];
////////////////////////
// bottom nav bar navigator function
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
/////////////////////
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: _screens.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),

      //bottomNavBar
      bottomNavigationBar: createBottomNavBar(),

    );
  }

///////////////////

// bottom navigation Bar
  Widget createBottomNavBar() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [primaryColor, secondaryColor],
          stops: [8, 8],
        ),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        iconSize: 22,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white24,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info),
            label: 'Notices',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            label: 'More',
          ),
        ],
        enableFeedback: true,
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've tried to use **pushReplacement** when moving from the bottomNav screen to the next one but it doesn't work.

So,
i.e.: How to keep the BottomNav visible in the screens that aren't directly attached to the BottomNav??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) package. It is easy to use and also has 20 different style.

> If you want to have your own style for the navigation bar, follow [these steps](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar#custom-navigation-bar-styling)

Here is an example of implementation;

```
class _PersistentNavBarState extends State<PersistentNavBar> {
  late PersistentTabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    super.initState();
  }

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      HomeScreen(title: 'Home'),
      NoticesScreen(),
      ProfileScreen(),
      MoreScreen(),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: ('Home'),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.info),
        title: ('Notices'),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
        title: ('Profile'),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
        title: ('More'),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Default is Colors.white.
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
          true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
      stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows:
          true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
      decoration: NavBarDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
      ),
      popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
      popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
      itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
        // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
      screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
        // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
        animateTabTransition: true,
        curve: Curves.ease,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      ),
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle
          .neumorphic, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to hear it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PageView` to achieve your goal.

Example PageView:

```
class MainPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  MainPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final pageController = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: PageView(
          controller: pageController,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          onPageChanged: (_){},
          children: const <Widget>[
            FirstView(),
            SecondView(),
            ThirdView(),
            FourthView(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: const NavigationBarView(),
    );
  }
}
```

You need to create `PageController` to change the page on the screen when an item from `BottomNavigation` is selected.

If you have further questions, please don't hesitate to write in the comments.

Comment: thank you so much, this is a good approach.